# Cut text in set of two word

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I used `jq` to extract value from JSON file I stored the values in on variable as string

```
var=$(Jq-command)
# var now contain
# "Serge" "Haroche" "David J." "Wineland"
```

I want a script to split this string every two word and create new lines, so i can't get as output

```
output:
Serge Haroche
David J Wineland
```

I'm kinda new im not really confortable with awk/sed and i couldn't with cut.

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. Provide a valid one for be able to use `jq`

Comment: Thank you for your time i got the answer.

Comment: There is no need to use `sed`. You could use `jq -r '.Prize[].laureates[] | .firstname + " " + .surname'` on your `json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this sed script

```
var='"Serge" "Haroche" "David J." "Wineland"'
echo $var|sed -n 's/"\([^"]\+\)" "\([^"]\+\)" */\1 \2\n/gp'
```

Output

```
Serge Haroche
David J. Wineland
```

to remove last \n

```
echo -n $var|sed -n 's/"\([^"]\+\)" "\([^"]\+\)" */\1 \2\n/gp'
```

Comment: May i ask if there is a way to remove the last '\n' , if not i don't mind it.

Comment: echo -n  will remove it